# How to "unbind" Glassfish 3+ remote EJB lookups?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3

I am currently experimenting with remote EJB lookups from my stand-alone Swing application and access some EJB-beans located on the Glassfish 3+ server by following code:

```
facade = (MyFacadeRemote)ServerContext.getInitialContext().lookup("java:global/MyProjectEE/MyProjectEE-ejb/MyFacade!com.myproject.MyFacadeRemote");
```

After some time I get some strange CORBA exceptions related with time-outs and even Heap-Overflow exceptions...

```
[#|2013-12-10T17:35:42.927+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|[10/Dec/2013:17:35:42 CET] ERROR [B3068]: Could not start the Broker's portmapper service on port 7676.
This port is already in use by another application -- possibly another
instance of the Broker. Please quit that other application, or use a
different port number for this instance of the Broker.
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
|#]

[#|2013-12-10T17:35:47.331+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|grizzly|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|doSelect exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error invoking PortMapperClientHandler.handleRequest. Cause null
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jms.system.ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.handleRequest(ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.java:2221)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ServiceInitializerHandler.onAcceptInterest(ServiceInitializerHandler.java:116)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectorHandlerRunner.handleSelectedKey(SelectorHandlerRunner.java:301)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectorHandlerRunner.handleSelectedKeys(SelectorHandlerRunner.java:263)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectorHandlerRunner.doSelect(SelectorHandlerRunner.java:200)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectorHandlerRunner.run(SelectorHandlerRunner.java:132)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jms.system.ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.handleRequest(ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.java:2218)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Should not call PortMapper.handleRequest() unless Broker has been started with the -noBind argument
    at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsserver.service.PortMapper.handleRequest(PortMapper.java:711)
    ... 13 more
|#]

[#|2013-12-10T17:48:49.085+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|grizzly|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|doSelect exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
|#]

[#|2013-12-10T17:52:36.432+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security|_ThreadID=273;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|iiop.login_exception|#]

[#|2013-12-10T18:02:41.024+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=103;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB MemoryFacade, method: public void ch.lawsuite.control.MemoryFacade.generateMemorySnapshot()|#]

[#|2013-12-10T18:07:57.920+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=103;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5215)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5113)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.callEJBTimeout(BaseContainer.java:4088)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.deliverTimeout(EJBTimerService.java:1832)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.access$100(EJBTimerService.java:108)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService$TaskExpiredWork.run(EJBTimerService.java:2646)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
|#]

[#|2013-12-10T18:22:18.079+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|grizzly|_ThreadID=20;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|doSelect exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
|#]

[#|2013-12-10T18:22:39.159+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|grizzly|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|doSelect exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
|#]

[#|2013-12-10T18:23:47.628+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB MemoryFacade, method: public void ch.lawsuite.control.MemoryFacade.generateMemorySnapshot()|#]

[#|2013-12-10T18:23:41.116+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.corba.ORBUtil|_ThreadID=284;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|IOP00010002: Unknown user exception thrown by the server - exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError; message: Java heap space
org.omg.CORBA.UNKNOWN: WARNING: IOP00010002: Unknown user exception thrown by the server - exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError; message: Java heap space  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 2 completed: Maybe
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.runtimeexception(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.convertThrowableToSystemException(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1843)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleThrowableDuringServerDispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1793)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleThrowableDuringServerDispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1758)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:255)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1624)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1486)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:990)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:742)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2324)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
|#]

[#|2013-12-10T18:32:38.370+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.corba.ORBUtil|_ThreadID=54;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|IOP00010002: Unknown user exception thrown by the server - exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError; message: Java heap space
org.omg.CORBA.UNKNOWN: WARNING: IOP00010002: Unknown user exception thrown by the server - exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError; message: Java heap space  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 2 completed: Maybe
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.runtimeexception(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.convertThrowableToSystemException(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1843)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleThrowableDuringServerDispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1793)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleThrowableDuringServerDispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1805)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleThrowableDuringServerDispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1758)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1494)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:990)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:742)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2324)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
|#]

[#|2013-12-10T18:32:10.495+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=73;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|In main loop, we have serious trouble: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space|#]

[#|2013-12-10T18:31:38.170+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|grizzly|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|doSelect exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
|#]

[#|2013-12-10T18:27:05.163+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5215)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5113)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.callEJBTimeout(BaseContainer.java:4088)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.deliverTimeout(EJBTimerService.java:1832)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.access$100(EJBTimerService.java:108)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService$TaskExpiredWork.run(EJBTimerService.java:2646)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
|#]

[#|2013-12-10T18:35:59.512+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=73;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
|#]

[#|2013-12-10T18:35:40.019+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.corba.ORBUtil|_ThreadID=284;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|IOP00710134: Exception occurred in handleRequest for a Request message
org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: WARNING: IOP00710134: Exception occurred in handleRequest for a Request message  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 134  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.exceptionInHandleRequestForRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1499)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:990)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:742)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2324)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: IOP00410003: Write error sent  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 3  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor178.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.writeErrorSend(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.writeLock(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:943)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.BufferManagerWriteStream.sendFragment(BufferManagerWriteStream.java:147)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.BufferManagerWriteStream.sendMessage(BufferManagerWriteStream.java:165)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.finishSendingMessage(CDROutputObject.java:200)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.sendResponse(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1554)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1497)
    ... 7 more
|#]

[#|2013-12-10T18:36:22.721+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5119:Expunging timer ['15@@1386093193458@@server@@domain1' 'TimedObject = MemoryFacade' 'Application = LawSuiteEE' 'BEING_DELIVERED' 'PERIODIC' 'Container ID = 90838993582293076' 'Wed Dec 04 12:00:00 CET 2013' '0' '0 # 0 # */6 # * # * # * # * # null # null # null # true # generateMemorySnapshot # 0' ] after [2] failed deliveries|#]

[#|2013-12-11T00:00:00.002+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|ch.lawsuite.services.NachrichtenService|_ThreadID=102;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Chat history older than a month successfully deleted [#0].|#]

[#|2013-12-11T00:13:58.617+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.corba.ORBUtil|_ThreadID=124;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|IOP00710134: Exception occurred in handleRequest for a Request message
org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: WARNING: IOP00710134: Exception occurred in handleRequest for a Request message  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 134  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.exceptionInHandleRequestForRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1499)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:990)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:742)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2324)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: IOP00410003: Write error sent  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 3 completed: Maybe
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor178.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.writeErrorSend(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.sendWithoutLock(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:999)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.BufferManagerWriteStream.sendFragment(BufferManagerWriteStream.java:151)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.BufferManagerWriteStream.sendMessage(BufferManagerWriteStream.java:165)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.finishSendingMessage(CDROutputObject.java:200)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.sendResponse(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1554)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1497)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:94)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:450)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.write(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:652)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.writeTo(CDROutputObject.java:234)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.sendWithoutLock(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:985)
    ... 12 more
|#]
```

Do I need to release these remote references somewhen, somehow ? How would I accomplish such a release ?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Post examples of the exceptions you get, until then it will be speculation what is the real root of the problem.

Comment: hi gimby, I added the corresponding server log. many thanks for your help!